# pyTigerGraph upsertVertexDataFrame attributes won't accept operator tuple

Tags: python, vertex-attributes, tigergraph

```
attributes = { 'id' : 'id', 'volume' : ('volume', '+') }

upsertVertexDataFrame(df=df, vertexType=type, attributes=attributes)
```

Traceback
row 1269 of pyTigerGraph.py in upsertVertexDataFrame() (else {target: json_up[-1][source])

row 1269 of same in (.0)

KeyError: ('volume', '+')

I have not tried this format in upsertVertices yet. That's next.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed not implemented yet. You might want to report this as a [new issue](https://github.com/tigergraph/pyTigerGraph/issues).